# What is the equivalent of the SystemEvents.SessionEnded Event for C++?

Tags: c++, events, session

I'm coding with C++ in unmanaged WinAPIs environment.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `WM_ENDSESSION` windows message

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376889(v=vs.85).aspx

```
LRESULT MyWindowProc(HWND hwind, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  switch (msg) {
    case WM_ENDSESSION: 
      // Session ended.  Just like SystemEvents.SessionEnded
      ...
      break;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it broadcast for a service application as well?

Comment: @user843732 no, this will only be sent to desktop applications. A service has no notion of a session since it's isolated from the desktop

Comment: For services, you can register for SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE notifications in your HandlerEx() implementation.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683241(v=vs.85).aspx